# How can i change the background cell color after the user edited some text

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, colors

Going from the previous question i had asked that related to color text change after edit. Now it has been requested that i should not highlight the edited text but change the background color.

This is what i want now.

1. Load existing file with the data to the `DataGridView`
2. After loading, `DataGridView` will populate data
3. The user will edit text from any cell
4. After editing the text,
5. Background color of the edited cell will change color to red,
6. Only for the edited cell,

How can i change the background color of the edited cell in the `DataGridView` ?

This is what i tried by changing the background color of the cell.

```
   private void Gridview_Output_CellBeginEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
            DataGridViewCell cell = Gridview_Output[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
            cell.Tag = cell.Value != null ? cell.Value : "";

            if (cell.OwningColumn.Name == "ValueOut")
                cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
```

global

```
    List<DataGridViewCell> dgvc_List = new List<DataGridViewCell>();
```

Save button

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         dgvc_List.Add(cell);
                foreach (DataGridViewCell d in dgvc_List)
                {
                    d.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
                dgvc_List.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: You want to call `dgvc_List.Add(cell)` upon the `CellEndEdit` event, directly after `cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;` What you have above will not compile...

Comment: am trying to find a way which will help me clear the color when you click save. am trying to follow up with the example you provided me with

Comment: You should probably read up on some basic c# principals if you don't understand. Like the old saying goes, you definitely cant run before you can walk and probably should not try to walk before you can crawl. Have a look at [this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html) for a fairly thorough beginners guide that you may be able to use to help with certain aspects of the language that you do not yet understand... Persistence is the key! Best of luck...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the TextChanged event ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx ) to detect whenever the user is changing the content of the TextBox (you might want to apply some logic here to avoid to trigger it when loading the data in the control). When the even triggers, you can then change the Background color of the control ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2kh9x59(v=vs.110).aspx )

Answer (score 0):

Add a new event on CellEndEdit instead:

```
private void Gridview_Output_CellEndEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
        DataGridViewCell cell = Gridview_Output[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
        cell.Tag = cell.Value != null ? cell.Value : "";

        if (cell.OwningColumn.Name == "ValueOut")
            cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

This is because you invoke the event *before* the editing is done, instead what you really want is show a different color when the job is done.

Comment: There is something else that require beginEdit other than changing the color if edited? If not you can remove it. Please flag it as answered if this solved your problem.

Comment: simply add an event on the button click that iterate every cell of the datagrid and set the color to white:      
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
   { 
    foreach(DataGridViewCell c in r.Cells)
    {
     c.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
   }
  }

Comment: @Donbabbeo agree... Add it to the saveButton_Click method.

Comment: i don't understand here. I have save button, so how do you want me to do it. the user will edit from gridcell and click to  edit and then click save button.

Comment: I think we are already crossing the 'do it for me' line instead of 'help me understand'...
you have a button right? Add An event to that button when an user click it.
Inside that event iterate every cells of the grid and change its color.
just put the code up there into the event. it's pretty straightforward...

Comment: Both @Donbabbeo and I have explained it in fairly simple terms. What error are you getting? Or is it just not working as expected?

Comment: By the way... i don't seee any updated code, it's always the same here.

Comment: after clearing  my mind a bit, i manged to make it work. thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Just to further what Donbabbeo has answered...

I take it you only want to change the background **ONLY IF** the cell value has actually been changed. Using Donbabbeo's answer will change the `BackColor` regardless every time editing occurs irrespective of whether the value has changed or not.

I suggest you use both the `CellBeginEdit` and `CellEndEdit` events together.

To begin with you need to 'remember' the original value of the cell being edited.

```
string originalValue; // Define a global outside
    private void Gridview_Output_CellBeginEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        originalValue = Gridview_Output[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();  
    }
```

And then when you complete the edit you check back against the originalValue, only changing the background color if changes had actually been made

```
private void Gridview_Output_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
       DataGridViewCell cell = Gridview_Output[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
       if (cell.Value.ToString() != originalValue)
       {
           cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
       }                
   }
```

If you still want to check that the `OwningColumn.Name` is a specific value or any other checks for that matter then add a further `if` statement after you check against the original value.

**UPDATE**

Changing the cell colors back to their original should be done exactly as Donbabbeo has described in his comment **UNLESS** you are dealing with a very large `DataGridView` and then it would be much more efficient to create a generic list of cells to be added to when the change complets & then when saved iterate only through the `List<>` to revert.

It would be implemented something like this.

First of all the list would need to be declared outside

```
List<DataGridViewCell> dgvc_List = new List<DataGridViewCell>();
```

Once the list is declared you would then add specific cells once you were sure that the value was different to the original and that the the `BackColor` had been changed.

In saying that the following would then be added directly after the color change in the `CellEndEdit` event.

```
dgvc_List.Add(cell);
```

The list will then continue to grow with every confirmed edit until you were ready to do something with it upon the save method, or whatever other method you wanted really, where you would call the following

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell d in dgvc_List)
     {
         d.Style.BackColor = Color.White; // Or Any Color
     }
dgvc_List.Clear(); // Clears the list ready to go again
```

Its a little more to code but much more efficient in the long run.

Comment: how can i clear those colors after clicking save button

Comment: Your code throws an error; Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   on this line d.Style.BackColor = Color.White;

Comment: Did you follow the update including the declaration of the `List<DataGridViewCell>` ? An object reference exception means that you have not... Or you are picking pieces and trying to use elsewhere without the correct declarations...

Comment: Have you declared the list outside of your method(s)?